# how can i call a function in a onclick method of image button in asp.net

Tags: javascript, asp.net, html

I have to call a function to send some data in onclick method

```
   <div class="yildiz"><asp:ImageButton ID=Imageid runat="server" Height="19px" 
                            ImageUrl="~/images/yildiz.png" onclick= "<%= someFunction('das') %>" Width="20px" 
                            style="position: relative; top: 13px; left:6px; float:left; "   /></div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `OnClientClick`, like so:

```
<asp:ImageButton
   ID=Imageid runat="server"
   Height="19px"
   ImageUrl="~/images/yildiz.png"
   OnClientClick="someFunction('das')"
   Width="20px"
   style="position: relative; top: 13px; left:6px; float:left; "
/>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, the code works but the function cannot be called

Comment: I guess I'm having problems understanding what you're trying to do.  I assumed `someFunction()` was a JavaScript function, as you were using single quotes - thus my method would be correct.  If you are trying to call a serverside method, just use `OnClick` - However, you cannot explicitly pass variables in.  You would need to use the [ImageButton.CommandArgument](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.imagebutton.commandargument.aspx) property for that.

Answer (score 0):

asp.net side

```
<div class="yildiz"><asp:ImageButton ID=Imageid runat="server" Height="19px" 
   ImageUrl="~/images/yildiz.png" 
   OnClientClick="SomeMethod(<% j%>,  <% imageid%>)" Width="20px" 
   style="position: relative; top: 13px; left:6px; float:left; "   />
```

C# side
   public void SomeMethod(int numberOfStar,string imageId)
        {

```
        this.baslik2.Text = "dsadsadsa";
        this.baslik.Text = "fasfsa";
        ImageButton4.ImageUrl = "images/yildiz-secili.png";
        ImageButton2.ImageUrl = "images/yildiz-secili.png";
    }
```

also i tried to call javascript function like

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
                        function SomeMethod(int j, string imageidd){
                            javascript: window.open("http://www.microsoft.com");
                             ImageButton2.ImageUrl = "images/yildiz-secili.png";
                        }    

</script>
```